# Lower and upper bound for trigonometric functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, upper-lower-bounds

Consider the function $f:\{x\in\mathbb{R}, x\neq k\pi, k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f(x) =\frac{\sin^4 x -\cos x}{\sin^3 x}.$$

As an exercise of my calculus class, the Professor asked to find an upper and lower bound for that function.

Actually, the unique bounds I know for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are $-1\le\sin x, \cos x\le 1$, so I don't know to obtain an upper/lower bound in this case.

Moreover, for $x\sim 0$, the term $1/\sin^3 x$ tends to infinity and then I don't know how to manage it.

Could someone please help me to find the bound for this function?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about $ f(n\pi)$?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I apologize, I edited the question.

Comment: Your function is unbounded.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah would you answer with a proof? If you want. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The behavior near zero is **very important** and can be studied both to the left and right of zero using Taylor expansions, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $ x $ in the domain, we can write
$$f(x)=\sin(x)-\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^3(x)}$$
$$=g(x)+h(x)$$
As you know, the function $ g $ is bounded by $ -1$ and$ 1$, But

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}h(x)=\frac{-1}{0^-}=\infty$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}h(x)=\frac{-1}{0^+}=
-\infty$$

thus, the function $ f $ is not bounded .